# Which software and tools should I use to create software presentation like this one?

Tags: software-rec, screen-capture, video-editing, screencasts, audio-recording

I want to create a screen captured audio (microphone) - video presentation of my software. So i'm looking for best screencasting softwares out there which should allow me to edit recorded audio and video as well as adjust audio.. fast-forward specific portion of video.. zoom in and out specific portions in real-time without loosing quality as well as few cool effects on software window. Please check following 3 videos :

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7zmOYziFKZw
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F0QXB5pw2qE
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mk-O22wu-kc
```

From those videos, i'm looking for following features :

- I would like to have text typing
  effect.
- The browser window is tilted a little
  when typing to give really cool 3d
  like effect.
- Zooming of specific potions really
  look cool in real-time without
  loosing any graphic quality.

Please suggest me softwares and tools i can use to create similar video presentation. It doesn't matter even if the software and tools are commercial/paid products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not just one software, but using several to get the effect you want. Look into--

- good video editing software (camtasia, kdenlive on linux)
- prezi
- blender or 3d animation software
- inkscape or gimp

*these are mostly Free & open source software (FOSS) as I use them myself.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.. I did check all of those... but it seems like a way too much work in there if i choose to go that way. .. do you know by any chance if adobe captivate could help me to product that kinda quality software simulation???

Comment: blender indeed comes with a steep learning curve. i'm only skimming the surface with it. i run linux on my pc--i don't know if adobe captivate can handle such projects.